# How can I implement a custom print destination in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, printer, network-printer

If `ctrl + P` is triggered in Chrome, a "print" window will pop up and several print destinations will be provided, such as "save as pdf", "save to Google Drive", and available printers.

My scenario is that I have a printer whose printing jobs can only be submitted through a web interface (log in with an account, pay money, submit a job, and at last, get your paper). The printer does not accept a normal printer's connection protocol. Therefore, it can not be simply added as one of the destinations.

In such a case, I would like to implement a customized script that can be invoked each time I try to print the current web document (`ctrl + P`). The script may accept a pdf document as input, and do customized jobs (in my case, it is automatically log in and then upload the pdf).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think implementing a windows printer driver might be a final solution but I haven't got time to try yet.